# ExtJS 4.X.X disable all panels at once

Tags: extjs, panels

How would I disable all forms and panels in ExtJS at once, ideally before function call and then enable after the function is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ExtJS 4, you can do something like this...

```
var panels = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel');
if (panels.length) {
    for (var i = 0, l = panels.length; i < l; i++) {
        panels[i].disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loadmask to the body element. That should have the same effect. Hide the loadmask when the function completes.